# Is there a method (java) for use both the methods executeupdate and executequery?

Tags: java, sql

On my program (client - server), sometimes the client send to server a query for example : "select from ....", so on server there is executeQuery, and sometimes the client send to client a query for example : "insert into.... ", so on server there is executeUpdate.
I want a method that i can use  for executeQuery and executeUpdate.

Comment: don't know if there is one, but you can always write your own.

Comment: So you're sending SQL request string from client to server? Smells like SQL injection.

Comment: It is a project for the university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing Query `String` than at Server\Client when you receive the query decide your path.

- Create Different Methods for Execution of different queries and pass parameter as `String`(Query) or you can use conditional statements to provide proper execution according to String.
- By the use of String Methods like `queryString.startsWith("insert")` to find appropriate method for execution and decide whether go for `insert/update/select` or anything else.

---

And yes as *user432* has suggested it would be better to go for `execute()` which can execute any kind of SQL Statement.

But for Queries which returns data you need to use Methods on `statement` Object Like.

- `getResultSet()`
- `getUpdateCount()`

Comment: Yes, I used the method that user432 has suggested, work! thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

At an API level, this would be a non-sense to have the same method for both, as they do return different objects. The `executeUpdate()` method returns the number of rows that were affected by your update, whereas the `executeQuery()` method returns a ResultSet containing all your results, which is very handy.